# Create featured image from a remote url when creating a post

Tags: uploads, media

I am trying to scrape an image from a remote url that is added using a text field in Advanced Custom Fields (hardcoded in the example below), but I don't even know if the process I am using is correct. I read multiple sources, but different functions and techniques are used (media_sideload_image, wp_remote_get, etc), so I am a bit confused.

I used multiple sources to create the following code.

The scraper from here (tested on its own for the following example, works just fine): https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/extract-image-php/

I used some info on this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368072/error-in-fetching-image-using-wp-remote-get-function

And the docs:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload

So here is my code:

```
function generate_featured() {
    global $post;
    if($update == false) {
        if ( !function_exists('media_handle_upload') ) {
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }

        $url = 'https://www.google.gr';
        $html = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match_all( '|<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>|i',$html, $matches );
    $image_url = $url . $matches[1][0];

        $tmp = download_url( $image_url );
        $file_array = array(
        'name'     => $post_id . '_' . $image_url . '_' . basename( $matches[1][0] ),
        'tmp_name' => $tmp
        );

        // Check for download errors
        if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
            @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
            return false;
        }

        $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id );

        // Check for handle sideload errors.
        if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
            return false;
        }

        // Set post thumbnail.
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $id );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'generate_featured', 10, 3 );
```

The thing is I don't see any files created on the `wp-content/uploads` directory.
I temporarily used the `media_sideload_image($file, $post_id, $desc);` function and the file gets created properly but cannot then set it as a featured image.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The code worked for me; but I defined the `function` like this: `function generate_featured( $post_id )`, then I commented out the `global $post;`; and finally (although this is not mandatory..), in the `$file_array`, I set `name` like this: `'name'     => basename( $image_url ),`

Comment: let me give it a try and get back to you

Comment: You are right! Now works, but I am not getting the expected behavior. As soon as I create a new post I see the image already attached as a featured image. I would expect hat this would appear after saving the post - since the ACF field intended to do the scrape is created only after I select a category. Maybe I am using the wrong action hook?

Comment: ...I mean I would expect this to run only after I git the 'publish' button

Comment: I just used 'publish_post' and seem to be getting the expected outcome. I am at work though, between stuff and won't be able to verify this works as intended until later today.

Comment: Actually, I'd use [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/); but to capture the `$update` value, you'd define the `function` like this: `function generate_featured( $post_id, $post, $update )`.

Comment: Since I want to use an ACF field in order to use the url, I used the custom `acf/save_post` hook.

Comment: I am getting a 'forbidden' error when using the `download_url` to download a file from a CDN. Is this normal?

Comment: What CDN is that? Perhaps they require some kind of authentication/authorization.

Comment: @SallyCJ It's is the CDN used from `medium.com`. However, since multiple sites were supposed to be scraped, and didn't want to risk same errors, or maintaining each site/cdn separately, I took a different direction and decided to just save the fb meta image on each post and load it from its source directly. Also, please make your comment as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code worked for me; but I defined the function like this: `function generate_featured( $post_id )`, then I commented out the `global $post;`; and finally (although this is not mandatory..), in the `$file_array`, I set name like this: `'name' => basename( $image_url ),`

So: *(Note that I intentionally didn't include the whole code)*

```
function generate_featured( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    //global $post;
    if($update == false) {
        ...

        $tmp = download_url( $image_url );
        $file_array = array(
        'name'     => basename( $image_url ),
        'tmp_name' => $tmp
        );

        ...

        // Set post thumbnail.
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $id );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'generate_featured', 10, 3 );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/ if you need (further) help with the `save_post` hook.